# How do you scroll a list in AppMaker?

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a list widget with five rows per page.  When the user goes to the next page I reload the page (by doing an unload/load on the data source with the new page number) and that works fine.  However, the list stays scrolled to the bottom.  How can I scroll the list to the top so the user does not have to?

I tried the ways that work in standard HTML but they do not work in AppMaker, and I cannot find any documentation on how to do this.

Thanks for any tips or pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the desired behavior by doing the following:

1. In the outline, locate the **TablePanel** widget and select the **List:TableBody** widget
   [image]

2.In the property editor, scroll to the **Events** section and click on the **onDataLoad** event value. Then click on *Custom Action*.
[image]

3. Type in this code `var elem = widget.getElement(); elem.scrollTop = 0;` so that it looks like this
   [image]
4. Make sure the change is saved and then preview your app and it should work. Let me know if you need something else or if it don't work.

Comment: This is perfect!  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old post, but for future visitors, here's what worked for me - you need to set the index of the list to zero. App Maker ensures that it scrolls the last selected item into view, and maintains this across navigations.

You can do this by passing in a callback function that runs after loading the list. For me, I reload the list from a dropdown widget that filters the list, so in the onValueChange event I've added:

```
// Load datasource
widget.datasource.load(function() {
  // Set index to 1 to ensure we scroll to top of list
  app.datasources.YOURDATASOURCE.selectIndex(0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For me Morfinismo's answer didn't work, but the following did:
In the style editor add CSS for the List element:

```
.app-pageName-nameOfTheListWidget {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

And in the *Property Editor* under *Layout* set a *Max height*.